# Cartan's Lemma on a disjoint union of $g$-translates

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, manifolds, complex-geometry, group-actions

Let $X$ be a complex manifold equipped with an action of a finite group $G$ by automorphisms of $X$. Assume that $x$ is a point on $X$ with stabilizer ${\rm Stab}(x)=:H$. Let $U$ be an $H$-invariant neighbourhood of $x$ such that $U\cap gU=\emptyset$ for all $g\in G/H$. What is the correct way of applying Cartan's Lemma on the disjoint union $\cup_{g\in G/H}gU$ of translates of $U$ simultaneously?
Is $\cup_{g\in G/H}gU$ biholomorphic to a disjoint union $\cup_{g\in G/H}gV=G\times_HV\subset G\times_HT_xX$, where $V\subset T_xX$ is an open $H$-invariant subset? More concretely, what I mean is, $\cup_{g\in G/H}gU$ is not biholomorphic to a set in the induced representation ${\rm ind}_H^GT_xX:=\mathbb CG\otimes_{\mathbb CH}T_xX$ of $T_xX$, but in $G\times_HT_xX$?

Comment: I do not understand the premise of the question: The union you are starting with is not disjoint, $\cup_{g\in G/H} gU$. Do you really mean forming a disjoint union $\amalg_{g\in G/H} gU$ (which, then, is not a subset of $X$)? Also, in order to apply Cartan, more care needs to be made regarding a choice of $U$. Imagine for instance $G=\{1\}$ and $U=X$, where $X$ is compact.

Comment: Why is the union not disjoint? The sets are disjoint, and their union is disjoint. That is what I meant. Maybe I should have said a union of disjoint subsets? I regard the disjoint union of $gU$'s as a subset of $X$. By Cartan.s lemma, I mean that every point $x$ with stabilizer $Stab(x)=H$ in $X$ has an $H$-invariant neighbourhood, which can be $H$-equivariantly and  biholomorphically mapped on an $H$-invariant open subset in $T_xX$. My subset $U$ in the question above satisfies this.

Comment: Sorry, I was misreading the question when I said that the subsets are not disjoint. But my second remark stands: You have to choose $U$ better than you did in order to apply  Cartan's result. The assumption that $U$ is $H$-invariant and $gU\cap U\ne \emptyset$ iff $g\notin H$ is not enough for this. Once you have chosen $U$ small enough, then indeed $GU$ is equivariantly biholomorphic to an open subset in the $G$-orbit of a suitable open subset $V\subset T_xX$.

Comment: Thank you. Let me first clarify your first remark. You were probably confused by the notation $\cup$ and the talk about disjoint union (coproduct), which is denoted as $\coprod$. I think that in my concrete case, however, $\cup_{g\in G/H}gU=\coprod_{g\in G/H}gU$. As for the second part, I disagree with your comment. Namely, the tangent space $T_xX$ does not have a $G$-action, only an action by $H$. So, when we apply Cartan's lemma on the set $\coprod_{g\in G/H}gU$, the set is biholomorphically mapped on an open subset in something like $\coprod_{g\in G/H}T_{gx}X$.

Comment: For my first remark, it was just the result of me not reading what you wrote carefully. For the second, I am not claiming of course that $G$ is acting on $T_xX$, it is acting on $TX$. But in the example I gave, $G=1$ and $U=X$ is compact. Thus, this $U$ satisfies your hypothesis, but there is no biholomorphic embedding of $U$ in $T_xX$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. What does your sentence "**Once you have chosen $U$ small enough, then indeed $GU$ is equivariantly biholomorphic to an open subset in the $G$-orbit of a suitable open subset $V\subset T_xX$.**" refer to? The special case $G=1$, $U=X$ compact or in general?

Comment: This sentence refers to is the general case. The example $G=1$ etc. is only meant to show that your stated assumptions are insufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, let me check if I have understood you correctly. After I have chosen $U$ sufficiently small, that is, Cartan's lemma applies to $U$, meaning there is an $H$-invariant open $V$ in $T_xX$ and an $H$-equivariant bihomolomorphism $U\cong V$, then $\coprod_{g\in G/H}gU\cong\coprod_{g\in G/H}gV=G\times_HV\subset G\times_HT_xX$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Right..........

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $U\subset X$ is an $H$-invariant neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ such that:

1. $gU\cap U\ne \emptyset \iff g\in H$.
2. There exists a neighborhood $V\subset T_xX$ of $0$ and a biholomorphic $H$-equivariant map $h: U\to V$.

I will equip $GV\subset TX$ with the induced complex structure. Then:

Lemma. There exists an equivariant biholomorphic map $f: GU\to GV$.

Proof. Given $z\in gU$, define $f(z)= dg \circ h \circ g^{-1}(z)$. Equivariance of $h$ shows that this formula defines a map $f: GU\to GV$.  This map is a composition of three holomorphic maps, hence, is holomorphic. The inverse to this map is given by $g\circ h \circ dg^{-1}$, which is well-defined and holomorphic for the same reason as above. qed

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I apologise for my persistence, but isn't $GV$ biholomorphic precisely to $G\times_HV\subset G\times_HT_xX$ by construction? Also, why is $V$ open in $TX$? It is open in the fiber $T_xX$, but $T_xX$ is closed in $TX$ as the preimage of a point on the base space. Why is it open?

Comment: Where did I say it is open in $TX$? And yes to the first question, of course.

Comment: Aha, ok. So, you do not treat $GV$ as an open subset of $TX$. Good! I assumed that as $GU$ is open in $X$. I apologise for the misunderstanding. Thank you for the discussion.